# Using ng-annotate failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) on my angular application but does not work at all.

I have configuration part:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';


    angular.module('app')
        .config(/*@ngInject*/ routes);

    function routes ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/view.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });

        $stateProvider
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/signup',
                templateUrl: 'app/signup/view.html',
                controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }

})();
```

and when I run angular app, then I've got the error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:strictdi] routes is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/strictdi?p0=routes
```

and the ng-annotate is implemented in my gulp config file:

```
gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
    var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(options.tmp + '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js', { read: false });
    var partialsInjectOptions = {
      starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
      ignorePath: options.tmp + '/partials',
      addRootSlash: false
    };

    var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html');
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
    var assets;

    return gulp.src(options.tmp + '/serve/*.html')
      .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
      .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
      .pipe($.rev())
      .pipe(jsFilter)
      .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
      .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', options.errorHandler('Uglify'))
      .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
      .pipe(cssFilter)
      .pipe($.csso())
      .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
      .pipe(assets.restore())
      .pipe($.useref())
      .pipe($.revReplace())
      .pipe(htmlFilter)
      .pipe($.minifyHtml({
        empty: true,
        spare: true,
        quotes: true,
        conditionals: true
      }))
      .pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dist + '/'))
      .pipe($.size({ title: options.dist + '/', showFiles: true }));
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your example through `ng-annotate -a example.js` (`npm install -g ng-annotate` first) and you'll see that routes is properly annotated. You can skip the `/*@ngInject*/` comment for it if you want to, it's not needed.

I'd guess that your problem is that you're doing `controller: 'MainCtrl'`instead of `controller: MainCtrl`. ng-annotate has no way of following the reference if it's a string literal so change it or make sure to do an explicit ngInject on MainCtrl itself.